# I have a question about running Linux csh multiple scripts

Tags: linux, csh

```bash
#!/bin/csh

while(1)
ps | grep -v "PID" | head -1 > /export/home/system/system/tmp/ppp
set pts = `awk -f: '{print $2}' /export/home/system/system/tmp/ppp`
echo $pts[1] > /export/home/system/system/tmp/ppp1
set ww = `cut -c5-6 /export/home/system/system/qtmp/ppp1`
clear

@ a = 0
echo "############################ "
echo " <  C3svr2 Quick-Check  >  "
echo "############################ "
echo " < Application count = 46 , Modify DATE = 2023.09.14 >  "
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------ "
echo " 9700/8700/7700/9300/8300 "
echo " 7300/gwchopan/ex_txt2chulpand/yunmon/m_embargod "
echo " rtf2chulgod/ex_xml2archived/newsis_con/newsis_rcv/newsis_reg "
echo " bloom_reg/get_bloom/pdf_rcv/ynewsml_reg/ex_jdistd.ns "
echo " ex_jdistd.ww/youtubed/smartx/logmond/snd_dotcom "
echo " im_photod/im_myphotod/img2chopan/im_dbd/im_sportsd "
echo " im_onlinephotod/im_arcphotod/im_newsisd/im_news1d/im_ftpd "
echo " im_getpicd/im_yond/ex_image2biz/ex_img2archived/get_pool "
echo " im_poold/tomcat/nmbd/smbd/sp1agentd/sp1mon "
echo " ----------------------------------------------------------------- "

ps -ef|grep nccs > /export/home/system/system/qtmp/qtmp.$ww
        foreach DDD( 9700 8700 7700 9300 8300 7300 gwchopan ex_txt2chulpand yunmon m_embargod rtf2chulgod ex_xml2archived newsis_con newsis_rcv newsis_reg bloom_reg get_bloom pdf_rcv ynewsml_reg ex_jdistd.ns ex_jdistd.ww youtubed smartx logmond snd_dotcom im_photod im_myphotod img2chopan im_dbd im_sportsd im_onlinephotod im_arcphotod im_newsisd im_news1d im_ftpd im_getpicd im_yond ex_image2biz ex_img2archived get_pool im_poold tomcat )
       cat /export/home/system/system/qtmp/qtmp.$ww | grep -w $DDD > /export/home/system/system/qtmp/qtmp1.$ww
      if ( $status == 1 ) then
           cat /export/home/system/system/qtmp/qtmp1.$ww | grep -v $DDD
           echo -n "$DDD""(Down)"
      else
           echo -n "! "
           @ a++
      sleep 0.3
      endif
      end

ps -ef|grep mbd > /export/home/system/system/qtmp1/qtmp.$ww

foreach DDD(nmbd smbd)

cat /export/home/system/system/qtmp1/qtmp.$ww | grep -w $DDD > /export/home/system/system/qtmp1/qtmp1.$ww

      if ( $status == 1 ) then
          cat /export/home/system/system/qtmp1/qtmp1.$ww | grep -v $DDD
           echo -n "$DDD""(Down)"
      else
           echo -n "! "
           @ a++
      sleep 0.3
      endif
      end

ps -ef|grep siem > /export/home/system/system/qtmp2/qtmp.$ww

foreach DDD(sp1agentd sp1mon)

cat /export/home/system/system/qtmp2/qtmp.$ww | grep -w $DDD > /export/home/system/system/qtmp2/qtmp1.$ww

      if ( $status == 1 ) then
        cat /export/home/system/system/qtmp2/qtmp1.$ww | grep -v $DDD
        echo -n "$DDD""(Down)"
      else
           echo -n "! "
           @ a++
      sleep 0.3
      endif
      end
echo " "
sleep 3
end
```

I created a script to check for daemons, but when I run the script on multiple PCs, sometimes it says that daemons that aren't dead are dead.
Why is that so?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Nsd.jpg)

Comment: For your concideration: [Top 10 Reasons not to use C Shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [Csh programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: Sorry, but your code is unreadable in this condition. Edit your Q. delete all of your code, paste in your code with proper indentation and line spacing as you have it in your `.csh` file, use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu at the top of the input box on the mouse-selected text of your code to have proper `clode/data/output/errMsg` formatting. Good luck.

Comment: Better yet, please read, reflect and act upon the section labeled [How to turn a bad script into a good qusetion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). The principles eplained there apply to all programing languages, Don't ignore because this is a bash.info item. It's very likely your problem stems from 1-2 lines of bad code. You'll resolve your problem faster if you narrow down your code to the one place that is causing the failure. A general principle about questions posted to StackOverflow is the question should be a [mcve]. Good luck.